# How to specify comment case owner

Tags: soap-api, case, case-comment

I am new using salesforce and I already created my case, and now I need to create comments from customer and customerSupport(both), but when I try to specify that in soap API like this:

https://xxxx/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/CaseComment

```
{
"CommentBody": "test",
"IsPublished": true,
"ParentId": "{xxx}",
"CreatedById": "{xxxxx}"                                        
}
```

The answer of the service is:

```
[
{
    "message": "Unable to create/update fields: CreatedById. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE",
    "fields": [
        "CreatedById"
    ]
}                                                                     
]
```

Maybe "CreatedById" is not a field correct to know who created the comment before, Can you help with this? I want to know where and how I can to define a case comment owner in some way

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable `Create Audit Fields` permissions from the SF UI to set createdById and CreatedDate

> Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation - Allow the user to set audit
>   fields (like "Created By" or "Last Modified By") when you create a
>   record via API importing tools like Data Loader.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213290&type=1

If you are using a System - Admin profile you have to create a permission set with `Create Audit Fields` mentioned in the below docs

**Create a Permission Set**

> 1. Go to Setup | Manage Users | Permission Sets.
> 2. Click New.
> 3. Enter Permission Set information such as 'Label' and 'Description'.
> 4. Optionally, specify a 'User license' to restrict this Permission Set to Users with specific licenses
> 5. Click Save.
> 6. On the next page, Go to System Permissions.
> 7. Click Edit.
> 8. Find 'Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation' and check the box for it. Note: If you do not see this option it's likely that 'Set Audit
>      Fields upon Record Creation' and 'Update Records with Inactive Owners'
>      is not currently enabled.
> 9. Click Save.

Assign the Permission Set

> 1. Go to Setup | Manage Users | Permission Sets.
> 2. Select the Permission Set for the 'Audit Fields.'
> 3. Click Manage Assignments.
> 4. Click Add Assignments.
> 5. Select the User to whom you want to assign the 'Permission Set.'
> 6. Click Assign.
> 7. Click Done.

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232909&type=1&language=en_US